# Efficiently toggle visibility on multiple images

Tags: jquery, performance, frontend

I have a chat web application that needs a hide/show avatars in chat setting.

How would you go about it an efficient way? So that you could easily show the images back and without parsing all the images.

*Posting this question and answering it for those who, as me, are in need of something like this*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for trying to add useful content to the site with your answer, but your question needs a LOT MORE detail, otherwise it might get flagged for closure as very low quality, or *Unclear What you're asking*. Please edit your question using the `edit` link and add more details, such as the problem

Comment: Thanks for the information, i have edited my question and hopefully it is more to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some might think it is ok to hide/show the images by querying like this :

Assuming class `.hide {display: none}` and default display state of an image is block.

Example code :

> ```
>  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
>
>  images.toggleClass('hide');
> ```

While this will work you would have to go through all the images which is constly.

A better way would be to grab the container of the images and make the images hide/show based on a class that could be toggled on the container itself.

Example code :

Having the following CSS :

> ```
> .hide .images {display: none;}
> ```

and the following jQuery :

> ```
> function toggleImages() { 
>
>    var container = $('#container');
>
>    container.toggleClass('hide'); 
>
> }
> ```

The end result would be this : The class would be toggled on the container and the css style would apply the changes.

Hope someone finds this helpful!An application of this would be the setting for a chat user to toggle the avatars in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example of a link that toggles image visibility

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" class="img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" class="img">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" class="img">

<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle images</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".toggle").click( function(e) {

    // Don't show # in url
    e.preventDefault()

    // The content to toggle
   $(".img").toggle()
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d0a7xofn/